# android bypass app chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

I understand that Android does not allow you to call an emergency number (911) directly. So I have decided to use Intent.ACTION_DIAL instead to leave the app and have the number pre-dialed, ready to call. However, the app chooser appears when I hit my 'Dial 911' button, adding another unnecessary step to the process (the other option besides the Phone app is to scan the number using Lookout Security).

Is there anyway to bypass the app chooser by pre-defining the app to handle the Intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible dialers. You have no good way of determining *a priori* which is the "one true dialer" that the user wants to use. Moreover, the user should be able to click "Always" on the chooser and therefore only encounter this once.

If you want, you could allow the user to choose their dialer up front, perhaps as part of configuring your app. You can use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to find out what all supports `ACTION_DIAL`, presenting that to the user to choose from. You would remember the `ComponentName` of their choice, and add that `ComponentName` to the `ACTION_DIAL` `Intent` that you use "for realz" when the user presses the button in your app.